# Textbook on "Generating Functions"

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions, book-recommendation

I have been looking on the net for a textbook that only is about "Generating Functions" but did not found much. Is there any textbook just about "Generating Functions"?

Comment: Maybe it would be expeditious to say what level of textbook you are seeking, e.g. upper level undergraduate, graduate level, or (?) research survey.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try  [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Answer (score 1):

Generatingfunctionology is the canonical undergraduate text.  The canonical graduate text is Flajolet and Sedgewick's [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/books.html).